# How do I route a sub-domain to a Cloud Storage folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Just today I started working on a new service that will upload your static site to **Google Cloud Platform or Amazon S3** and allow you to get a free sub-domain to view it at. How can I host the files in a folder on **Google Cloud Platform or Amazon S3** on a custom domain without it being like `mysite.example.com/dogsite/dog.html` and be like `mysite.example.com/dogs.html` instead? Currently, the documentation says nothing at all. I am *open* to other ideas too.

-- Yes, I am fine with using things like Nginx and Apache to route the CNAME --

Comment: You can't point a domain to a folder on a server using DNS. A domain points to a server/ip address, not a specific subfolder on that server. If you are running a web server yourself you can set the root folder that will be served as a webpage, but you don't have that control when you use something like S3.

Comment: @MarkB How do you think people like surge.sh do it?

Comment: They are running their own servers they can configure however they want. They most likely have some sort of proxy server like Nginx configured to route the requests to the appropriate location. Like I said, if you are running your own server you can do this, but if you want to use a service like S3, and that service doesn't have support to route your requests to a specific folder, then you can't do it. You definitely can't do it with pure DNS.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks, although how would I have it update the proxy when a new project is made with a custom domain?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  [Hosting a Static Website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)

Comment: @DanCornilescu Alexandre answered the question. Previous I was looking for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Google Cloud Storage directory as a domain root.

But, there is one solution :

1. For each subdomain, create a bucket (for example dogs-site-bucket).
2. Create a Google Cloud Loadbalancer

   - **Backend Configuration** : Add dogs-site-bucket as a Backend Bucket
   - **Host and path rules** : Create a new rule, example: host: mysite.example.com, path: dogs-site, backend: dogs-site-bucket
   - **Frontend Configuration** : Create a new front end with static IP and setup your DNS with this IP